# How to Select table name and value from one column from tables I get with a select?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Sorry, it sounds complicated, but the explanation is simple. I guess the answer no.

In a multisite (WP) I need to get two values from a column in all tables called xxx_options.

I have the script to get all the tables from two Schemas (wp, wp2):

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema  like 'wp%' and table_name like '%options';
```

I get:

```
1 wp_11_options
2 wp_12_options 
3 wp2_20_options
```

And I have a simple query to get the value:

```
SELECT option_value
FROM wp_10_options 
WHERE option_name = 'siteurl'
```

I need to know where I have a site URL so I need something like:

```
1 wp_11_options    https://example1.org
1 wp2_12_options   https://example4.org
```

Or I can use two values from "option_value":

```
option_id = 1 and 49
```

or

```
option_name = siteurl and upload_path (this file contain de number of the suffix, wp-**10**-options)
```

So I can get:

```
1 example1.com      wp-content/blogs.dir/10/files
```

I guess is like this super pseudo code:

```
Select table_name as name, table_name.wp_option_value 
From 
    (SELECT table_name 
     FROM information_schema.tables 
     WHERE table_schema like 'wp%' and table_name like '%options')
Order by table_name
```

Schemas: wp y wp2

Tables: LIKE '%options'

Fields: option_id, option_name, option_value

Values: option_id = 1 and 49 or table_name and option_name = 'siteurl'

Comment: You would have to use dynamic SQL for this.  I think the root of the problem is storing options values in separate tables.  They should all be in one table.

Comment: Nope, they shouldn't, for WordPress Multisite, all sites have different tables with specific prefixes (mostly site id like `wp_1_options`, `wp_2_options` etc.)